# faded text shows in custom keyboard android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am creating custom keyboard in android. I have read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) and also [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). I am referring to SoftKeyboard example. My problem is when I try to show keyboard with black color on key text the key shows with faded effect on key text. Please suggest me how do I remove this fad effect on text in keyboard. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding line

```
 android:shadowRadius="0.0"
```

in my keyboard layout.